# FormulaArray with variable concatenated into it

Tags: vba, excel, array-formulas

I'm trying to use VBA to insert a FormulaArray.  It works when I hardcode the cell rows but when I try to use a variable (shipRow) then I get the error "Unable to set the FormulaArray proprerty of the Range class".  In this example, shipRow = 4 and voyageColumn = 6

**THIS WORKS:**

```
Cells(shipRow + 6, voyageColumn).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(F$4,F$5,$B$1,G$5,F$7,D10,""Lower""),'Price Recs'!$2:$1048576,20,FALSE),"""")"
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

```
Cells(shipRow + 6, voyageColumn).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(F$" & Str(shipRow) & ",F$" & Str(shipRow + 1) & ",$B$1,G$5,F$7,D" & Str(shipRow + 6) & ",""Lower""),'Price Recs'!$2:$1048576,20,FALSE),"""")"
```

This is probably an easy fix that I just can't find!

Comment: `Str` is not a vba command.  It is `Cstr` and it is not needed here.  Just the use of `&` will turn the number to a string.  So remove all the `Str(...)`.  Just use the variable and math.

Comment: was about to answer, but Scott beat me to it :)

Comment: @ShaiRado feel free, I can and will remove my comment if you do.

Comment: I knew it would be easy, thanks!  I didn't have Str() before and was receiving the error but I must have accidentally fixed that error while adding Str().

Comment: @ScottCraner - Actually `Str` **is** a VBA command but, unlike `CStr`, `Str` places a leading space in front of positive numbers.  So `Str(12)` gives " 12" while `CStr(12)` gives "12".  Both `Str(-12)` and `CStr(-12)` give "-12".